# installing standalone Intune package

Tags: windows, deployment, windows-10, intune

We have some applications that have been converted to .intunewin format ready to load into our Intune server.

Is there a way I can install each Intune package manually either by command line or script on its own without having to connect\load them into a Intune server?

We want to be able to start up a virtual machine with no network connectivity install the packages and just check they install etc before loading them in?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, the .Intunewin format is basically a zip format that Endpoint can read. You should test your install files before wrapping them into the .intunewin format.

If you're worried about everyone seeing your packages in the Company Portal, just create a test group and assign the application there first.

Comment: Unfortunately I would like to test the install with actually connecting to the company portal. I was hoping there would be some sort of PowerShell command or a way of interacting with the Intune client that sits on the machine to say install this .IntuneWin package.